# Cannot locate scroller_x.swf file? Path is correct

Tags: php, javascript, html, flash, swfobject

For my website I am trying to use an image scroller. However I have uploaded scroller_x.swf multiple times and to different directories and it still cannot locate it. Also I am having a problem with an "Unexpected tolken ILLEGAL" when debugging with google chrome. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Website: www.ayaonline.com

Thanks,

Jacob

Comment: can you post more info on it? What directory + code used to call it in html?

Answer (score 0):

That "Unexpected token illegal" error usually happens when you add whitespace characters around the area where that error appears. Delete those and give it a try. (This also happens when you are copying from one site to another, and you grab invisible characters)

About the other problem, please post your code to see if there is any other mistake that we could help you with.